# XGBoost training keeps failing

Tags: apache-spark, xgboost

I'm trying to run any XGBoost code with Spark but without any success.
I also tried copy-pasting examples but these also do not work.
Let's say we have this example code: 
https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/_static/notebooks/xgboost-simple-example.html

Whenever I run XGBoost.trainWithDataFrame method, I always get this error when using binary:logistic objective:

```
Check failed: base_score > 0.0f && base_score < 1.0f base_score must be in (0,1) for logistic loss
```

I'm getting that error all the time with every train data, also changing other parameters does not help at all.

When using deprecated XGBoost.train I'm getting these errors(I increased rounds number to generate more of these errors):

```
[INFO] [06/25/2018 10:30:46.399] [RabitTracker-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://RabitTracker/user/Handler] [17] train-error:0.538462
[10:30:46] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[10:30:46] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[INFO] [06/25/2018 10:30:46.560] [RabitTracker-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka://RabitTracker/user/Handler] [18] train-error:0.538462
[10:30:46] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[10:30:46] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[INFO] [06/25/2018 10:30:46.720] [RabitTracker-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://RabitTracker/user/Handler] [19] train-error:0.538462
[10:30:46] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2[10:30:46] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc: pruned nodes, max_depth=0
74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[INFO] [06/25/2018 10:30:46.879] [RabitTracker-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://RabitTracker/user/Handler] [20] train-error:0.538462
[10:30:46] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:[10:30:46] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[INFO] [06/25/2018 10:30:47.040] [RabitTracker-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://RabitTracker/user/Handler] [21] train-error:0.538462
[10:30:47] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:[10:30:47] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[INFO] [06/25/2018 10:30:47.199] [RabitTracker-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://RabitTracker/user/Handler] [22] train-error:0.538462
[10:30:47] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0[10:30:47] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0

[INFO] [06/25/2018 10:30:47.359] [RabitTracker-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://RabitTracker/user/Handler] [23] train-error:0.538462
[10:30:47] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:[10:30:47] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: 74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
0
[INFO] [06/25/2018 10:30:47.519] [RabitTracker-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10] [akka://RabitTracker/user/Handler] [24]    train-error:0.538462
[10:30:47] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[10:30:47] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[INFO] [06/25/2018 10:30:47.679] [RabitTracker-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://RabitTracker/user/Handler] [25] train-error:0.538462
[10:30:47] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:[10:30:47] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[INFO] [06/25/2018 10:30:47.839] [RabitTracker-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://RabitTracker/user/Handler] [26] train-error:0.538462
[10:30:47] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:[10:30:47] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[INFO] [06/25/2018 10:30:48.001] [RabitTracker-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10] [akka://RabitTracker/user/Handler] [27]    train-error:0.538462
[10:30:48] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:[10:30:48] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 
0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[INFO] [06/25/2018 10:30:48.160] [RabitTracker-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://RabitTracker/user/Handler] [28] train-error:0.538462
[10:30:48] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:[10:30:4874: tree pruning end, 1 roots, ] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[INFO] [06/25/2018 10:30:48.319] [RabitTracker-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://RabitTracker/user/Handler] [29] train-error:0.538462
[10:30:48] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[10:30:48] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[INFO] [06/25/2018 10:30:48.479] [RabitTracker-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://RabitTracker/user/Handler] [30] train-error:0.538462
[10:30:48] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:[10:30:48] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 274: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth= pruned nodes, max_depth=0
0
[INFO] [06/25/2018 10:30:48.639] [RabitTracker-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] [akka://RabitTracker/user/Handler] [31] train-error:0.538462
[10:30:48[10:30:48] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 174: tree pruning end,  roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[INFO] [06/25/2018 10:30:48.799] [RabitTracker-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://RabitTracker/user/Handler] [32] train-error:0.538462
[10:30:48] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:[10:30:48] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
0
[INFO] [06/25/2018 10:30:48.960] [RabitTracker-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka://RabitTracker/user/Handler] [33] train-error:0.538462
[10:30:49] [10:30:49] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:/xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[INFO] [06/25/2018 10:30:49.119] [RabitTracker-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://RabitTracker/user/Handler] [34] train-error:0.538462
[10:30:49] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:[10:30:49] 74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
/xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[INFO] [06/25/2018 10:30:49.279] [RabitTracker-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka://RabitTracker/user/Handler] [35] train-error:0.538462
[10:30:49] /xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:[10:30:49] 74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
/xgboost/src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
```

Tested on SPark 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 2.3.0, Scala 2.11.

I'm using version 0.72 of xgboost.

I couldn't find any answer to my problem. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Mac? I had exactly the same problem with my Spark xgboost on Mac.

Here is some more info about this: [xgboost for JVM has test failures on OS X](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/2417)

I applied the suggested patch manually [Removed specializations for float/double parsing](https://github.com/dmlc/dmlc-core/pull/351) and it worked.

1. Clone repo
2. Change `include/dmlc/parameter.h` as suggested in the patch
3. Compile your xgboost code again

Comment: Thanks for reply! I'm using Ubuntu but I checked it. In this github issue user frenzykryger mentioned that this issue can be also fixed with setting env variables. Anyway, it fixed the issue, thanks a lot!